# See my election-relevant stats in the "nomination page"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, election

I think it would be beneficial to users who are nominating themselves if the "compose or edit my nomination" page showed the relevant stats, or at least badges. That way, potential nominees don't have to start digging through their profile for badges. I've got over a hundred and fifty of them.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://elections.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @YannisRizos yes, it should be on election page, that's what Moshe is asking i guess.

Comment: Badge requirements are also enforced at the code level, so nobody can nominate without having Strunk & White, Civic Duty, Deputy, and Convention.

Comment: Still makes it easier to see the badges.

Comment: @Lucifer There is a link to the stats page from the election page, so...

Comment: @YannisRizos Yup, see my edit, I'm referring to the text box that allows users to compose a self-nomination.